# Is there a way of getting an embed as a link or a link to an image

Tags: node.js, discord.js

I have all the messages that the discord bot detects sent to my console. I also made it so it sends all the links to the attachment. This is so I can see all the messages from visual studio. This is all fine. I have a problem though. I don't know how to be able to see embeds from the console. I want to be able to click a link from the console and see the embed. Is there any way of doing that.

If you are wondering here is the code for sending the message and attachment.

```
if(bot.user.id !== msg.author.id) console.log(`\n${msg.guild.name} || ${msg.channel.name} || ${msg.author.tag}: ${msg.content}`)
    let attam = 0
    msg.attachments.forEach(attachment=> {
        attam += 1
        console.log(`Attachment ${attam}: ${attachment.url}`)
    })
```

I figured out one way of solving my awnser. It is probably not that good but here is what I made.

```
console.log(msg.embeds.map(x => {
        attam ++
        let hmm = `embed ${attam}:`
        if(x.color){
            hmm = `${hmm}\nColor: ${x.hexColor}`
        }
        if(x.author){
            hmm = `${hmm}${x.author.iconURL? `\nAuthorImage: ${x.author.iconURL}`: ''}${x.author.name? `\nAuthor: ${x.author.name}`: ''}${x.author.url? `\nAuthorURL: ${x.author.url}`: ''}`
        }
        if(x.url){
            hmm = `${hmm}\nURL: ${x.hexColor}`
        }
        if(x.title){
            hmm = `${hmm}\nTitle: ${x.title}`
        }
        if(x.thumbnail){
            hmm = `${hmm}\nThumbnail: ${x.thumbnail.url}`
        }
        if(x.description){
            hmm = `${hmm}\nDescription: ${x.description}`
        }
        if(x.fields){
            let plus = 0
            x.fields.forEach(field => {
                plus++
                hmm = `${hmm}\nField ${plus}:\n   FieldTitle: ${field.name}\n   FieldValue: ${field.value}\n   Inline?: ${field.inline}`
            })
        }
        if(x.image) {
            hmm = `${hmm}\nImage: ${x.image.url}` 
        }
        if(x.footer){
            hmm = `${hmm}${x.footer.iconURL ? `\nFooterIcon: ${x.footer.iconURL}`: ''}${x.footer.text ? `\nFooterText: ${x.footer.text}`: ''}`
        }
        if(x.timestamp){
            hmm = `${hmm}\nTimestamp: ${x.timestamp}`
        }
        return hmm
        
    }).join("\n"))
```

I just discovered that there is a method for embeds called toJSON(). It does not actually convert it to an actual json string. It basically converts an embed to a simple object with properties. I all along could of just done.

```js
msg.embeds.forEach(embed => {
    console.log(embed.toJSON())  
})
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `message.embeds`; this is a `Collection` of `MessageEmbed`s.

```js
console.log(message.embeds.map(x => x.toString()).join("\n"))
```

Comment: this returns [object Object]. Anyway of that not happening. Sorry for the late response

Comment: Attempt: `console.log(require('util').inspect(message.embeds.map(x => x.toString()).join("\n"), { depth: 0 }));`

Comment: I sadly already created a bit of an alternative myself but thanks anyway.

Comment: Okay, make sure you post your alternative so we can provide feedback upon that and for future reference.

Comment: This was probably not the best option but I basically for each embed property I made a line like this.
embed property: value
---this included image links. If you want to see the code tell me.
Sorry for responding late

Comment: Please add all the code so other users who view this question will have a solid answer

Comment: I just found out a simpler way of doing it. It basically does what my last code does for me. It uses an embed function called .toJSON().

Answer (score 1):

You can do it like this

```js
client.on('message', (message) => {
    let images = message.embeds.map(embed => {
        if (embed.image) return embed.image
    })
});
```

Comment: This method will only return the embed's image; not the tnrei embed itself.

Comment: `or a link to an image`